# Local JS files not loading/running on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm running a nodejs application on Heroku. For simplicity's sake, I went through Heroku's example application steps. Once the application was up and running, I created a public/js/test.js file which contained a simple alert( 'testing' ); command.

I then came back to the view/partials/header.ejs file and included the new test.js file appropriately. Obviously, all of this works as intended locally - but when I push it to Heroku I get no alert. When I check source using developer's tools I see that it found the js file, but clicking on it reveals an empty file.

I assume that Heroku must require some sort of build step for this - but I haven't been able to find a specific path to getting it working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the Brave browser was interfering with the javascript file. I've never known Brave to cause a problem like this (and locally Brave did not break it). The issue must have something to do with how Heroku loads some of the static files.

Hopefully posting this answer will help someone else encountering the same issue.